# How do I set an interval, clear it, the reset the interval with the same exact ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

So basically I would like something like this

```
Inter = setInterval(Function, 1000);
clearInerval(Inter);
Inter = setInterval(Function, 1000);
```

For some reason something similar won't work for me, I'd post it all but I have no comments and no sense of organization. Is this supposed to work, or is their something I am missing?

Edit : Okay so I'll try to better explain this. So basically, I have an interval set, and a function to clear said interval. I need these to reset after every input, so the clearInterval has to recognize an interval with the same ID as it began with, so I need to basically re-use the ID, but for some reason it doesn't work. Hopefully thast madness made semi sense

Comment: `setInterval()` returns a new numeric timer ID every time you call it. It's perfectly OK to assign such a number to a variable that formerly held another timer ID. Other than that, I have no idea what you're asking.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this? I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a class that starts/stops an interval.

[Repl Example](https://repl.it/repls/SuperbRigidDatabases)

```
class Interval {
  constructor(duration, callback) {
    this.duration = duration
    this.callback = callback
  }
  get interval() { return this._interval }
  set interval(interval) { this._interval = interval }
  get duration() { return this._duration }
  set duration(duration) { this._duration = duration }
  get callback() { return this._callback }
  set callback(callback) { this._callback = callback }
  start() {
    this.interval = setInterval(this.callback, this.duration)
    return this
  }
  stop() {
    clearInterval(this.interval)
    return this
  }
}
```

**Instantiation**

```
let interval = new Interval(
  1000, 
  () => {
    console.log('interval')
  }
)
interval.start()
setTimeout(() => {
  interval.stop()
}, 5000)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't. The interval id "is a numeric, non-zero value which identifies the timer created by the call to setInterval()" and is generated automatically.

I would recommend changing the logic of your code but, if you insist, you could add all the ids in an array, which you would pass as a parameter to the function that erases the intervals. Then you would splice the ids as you kill the intervals.